# JQuery - calling event from onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a script for myself and there's a page with a button and when I click on that button it opens up menu.
So, here's the deal, I need somehow to programatically trigger that event which begins when user clicks on the button, here is the code of that element:

```
<a class="btn_green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Market_ShowPopup( 440, &quot;Some Text&quot;, &quot;Some text&quot; ); return false;">
<span>Some text...</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your statements in this function which should be executed before menu is opened:

```
document.querySelector('.btn_green').addEventListener('click',function(e){
            // Do something before menu is opened!
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you need like that

```js
$(document).on('click','.btn_green',function (){
Market_ShowPopup(440, "Some Text", "Some text")
})

function Market_ShowPopup (num,one,two){
  console.log(num+':'+one+':'+two)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn_green" >
<span>Some text...</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
$(.btn_green).click()
```

To trigger the click event on the button.